# De Rham Cohomology of the complement of an ellipse

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'll call $A$ the complement of an ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I know that $H^0(A)=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $H^k(A)=0$ if $k \ge 3$.
What about $k=1,2$?

I know that $A$ has two connected components, so $A=U_1 \cup U_2$, with $U_1$ simply connected (it is the interior part of the ellipse).
So $H^1(A)=H^1(U_2)$ and similarly for $H^2$. But what are the first and the second cohomology group of the exterior of the ellipse?

Comment: Your $A$ is diffeomorphic to the punctured plane, so essentially by definition, the cohomology groups of $A$ and the punctured plane agree. A harder theorem says that if two smooth manifolds are homotopy equivalent - they don't even have to be the same dimension! - they have the same de Rham cohomology groups, so you would just need to calculate the cohomology of $S^1$.

Comment: @Mike I think you mean that his $U_2$ is diffeomorphic to the punctured plane!